# Iframe and sharepoint compatibilty

Tags: 2010, browser-compatibility, iframe

I have a iframe where a user completes few courses and clicks finish at the end where we track the user activity as complete . This used to work with IE,chrome and mozilla.

Recently one of the users reported that on click of finish there is no activity happening . such that the event in iframe is not firing . If i click the compatibility icon everything works fine.

How do i resolve this compatibility issue ?

Comment: are you thinking alternate i.e using the Page viewr Web Part, as it is supported with all browser?

Comment: no , but page viewer internally also displays as an iframe .

Comment: which IE version you are using?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847836/browser-render-issue-in-iframe-inside-sharepoint-2007

Comment: IE9 and using these settings for campaibilty view http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/ie9-always-rendering-pages-in-ie7-compatibility/c0177b44-3950-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5

Comment: you mean if you enable it then it works or if you disable compatibility mode then it works?

Comment: when compatibilty mode is disabled , i have issues

Comment: Just add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />` (or different version, e.g. IE=10) to the page head. If that doesn't help, then we want to see the code that doesn't work.